# Android Studio Gradle Build Error

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed android studio 1.4. I started an app, and when I tried to run , it gave me the following error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)
> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
     \> http://proxy.iiit.ac.in
```

I checked connection for both the above links and checked them in the file > settings > HTTP PROXY , everything is works fine.

What should I do now ?

Answer (score -1):

Please add at build.gradle(Module.app)

```
    android {
         useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

You are not add to junit.jar or not dependency .jar file

Comment: Why does useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' should resolve the issue with the dependency of junit?

Comment: You answered the question wrongly or answered the wrong question :P